# Default editor for files without file name extension in Mac OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I want to open files without file name extension, including .dotsystemfiles (e.g. `.htaccess` or `.vimrc`) with a different editor than TextEdit. Doing the regular *Change All...* in the *Get Info* panel won't do the trick as it gives the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to change the editor for the `text/plain` mime type or `public.plain-text` UTI. The regular *Get Info* dialog changes the association for the file name extension, which these files don't have.

---

Get [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) and install it.

Open *System Preferences » Default Apps » Apps*. Select your desired default editor, and look for either of the above in the application's list of supported types.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Select the entry, and click *Set as Default*. You're done. Both opening from Finder and the command-line `open` will open your new default editor.

---

This also changes all `.txt` files and the like. I don't think this can be prevented, since OS X thinks both these and extension-less files are `public.plain-text`/`text/plain`.

---

To do this without *RCDefaultApp*, edit Edit `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`.

Add an entry under `LSHandlers`, containing the UTI (key `LSHandlerContentType`, e.g. `public.plain-text`) and application bundle identifier (`LSHandlerRoleAll`, e.g. `com.macromates.textmate`).

It looks like this in *Property List Editor*:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Or choose the Mime types tab and choose what app text/plain is opened by (this allows Aquamacs.app to be used which does not have the Mime types shown in its list

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot Daniel. A couple things to add: I needed to log out of the OS and then back in. Also, curiously, .DS_STORE files still open in TextEdit by default, but all other .dotsystemfiles are now opening in my desired editor.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with `defaults write` instead of downloading third party software?

Comment: @Matt See my edited post.

Comment: What's the difference between `text/plain` and `public.plain-text`?  Is there any reason other then @Mark's example to choose one over the other?

Comment: @Orion One is a [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type), the other is a [Uniform Type Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Type_Identifier). Just a different format to describe other document formats. They're usually easily interchangeable, which is why my answer contains both, except in cases like Mark's.

Comment: To set MacVim as the default, use "org.vim.macvim" for "LSHandlerRoleAll".

Comment: This does not work in macOS Mojave or higher. Can you please suggest what we do now? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can also run `plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` and add something like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>LSHandlerContentType</key>
    <string>public.plain-text</string>
    <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
    <string>com.macromates.textmate</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>LSHandlerContentType</key>
    <string>public.unix-executable</string>
    <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
    <string>com.macromates.textmate</string>
</dict>
```

You can apply changes by restarting or by rebuilding the Launch Services database. Logging out and back in isn't enough.

Or add this to a [duti](http://duti.org) configuration file:

```
com.macromates.textmate public.plain-text all
com.macromates.textmate public.unix-executable all
```

`public.plain-text` also includes files with a `.txt` or `.text` extension. I don't know any way to [change the default application for files with arbitrary extensions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60591/how-to-permanently-put-textedit-in-the-open-with-menu-list).

`public.unix-exexutable` includes executable scripts without a filename extension. If you try to change the default application for them from Finder, there is an error like this:

> **The operation can’t be completed.**
>
> An unexpected error occurred (error code -50).

Comment: duti is awesome! Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 1):

RCDefaultApp is sadly no longer available, but [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) is a modern replacement. It does not list MIME types, but I found that changing `public/data` on the "Uniform Type Identifiers" pane did the trick for files without an extension.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've had no luck with public.data but could instead add public.plain-text to MacVim in the Applications tab