# Mac: Change Default Text Editor

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default editor for files without file name extension in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/231854/default-editor-for-files-without-file-name-extension-in-mac-os-x)

The default is currently TextEdit. I want to change it to be MacVim.

I know how to set files that end with a certain extension, such as `.txt`, to always open with MacVim (I do this by selecting a file with the extension `.txt`, pressing command-i, and selecting Open with: Application, Change All...), but I also want text files without extensions, such as `README`, to open with MacVim by default.

Comment: I'm not closing this one as a dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/231854/default-editor-for-files-without-file-name-extension-in-mac-os-x as I feel the wording is completely different

Comment: The accepted solution may do the trick though.

Comment: @Ivo It is a duplicate. Both extension-less files and .txt share the text/plain MIME type and public.plain-text UTI, but the *Get Info* dialog only allows changes to the actual extension, therefore allowing `.txt` customization while leaving extension-less files alone. It is exactly the same issue. Matt only explicitly mentioned the what parts work for him, and jason (other topic) wants hidden files ("dot-files") to also work. Which they do, as they don't have an extension.

Comment: This is not a duplicate in my opinion either. The other one is specific to TextMate. It doesn't give enough information on how to make TextWrangler the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because it can't determine enough information about the file (other then it lacks an extension) to reliably alter that.

Comment: This argument doesn't hold up. OS X has enough information to decide to open it with TextEdit.