# Permanently change  defult application for a file type?

Tags: macos, macvim

How can I open all files of a certain type with a specific application? For instance, MacVim?

Selecting open with --> other --> select MacVim and checking "always open with" works for individual files but how can I always open files of a certain type with MacVim?

Comment: It would be more useful to others if you edited your question to not mention your specific text editor, or only as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the *Get Info* dialog of the file (in the *File* menu, or `Cmd-I`, or in the context menu). Then select to open with MacVim and click the *Change all…* button just below the application selection popup menu.

[image]

---

Use [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) (a System Preferences pane) to have greater control of file types.

---

If you want to control which application handles files without extension, see [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/questions/231854/default-editor-for-files-without-file-name-extension-in-mac-os-x/231867#231867).